# Advantage and disadvantage of CardView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-widget, android-cardview

What are the advantages and drawbacks of `CardView`, other than the shadow or elevation, what is the benefit in performance and looks? What is done using `CardView` can also be done using a combination of other layouts.

Comment: There's no difference in `CardView` and `ListView` except **shadows** and **rounded corners**.  You can do anything in listview that can be done in cardview

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Advantage of `Cardview` is definitely its default implementation of the shadow and the rounded corners, in simple words `Cardview` is just a FrameLayout with shadow and rounded corners. You can do almost the same stuff with a `Cardview` that you can do with a `Framelayout`(as `Cardview` extends `FrameLayout`). The `Cardview` for API>21 uses the elevation api to set the shadows whereas for below API 21 it adds a padding with grey background to create fake shadows(just similar to the custom implementation you were talking about).

`Cardview` is designed to hold a single child view within itself and would be very difficult to manage multiple child views without overlapping over each other as there is no support of property such as `layout_below`,`layout_torightof` etc.. to overcome this, the approach taken by developers would be to add another `Relativelayout` within the `Cardview` to manage the child views, now this would lead to more resource consumption due to nested layouts.

To handle complex layouts its recommended to use the custom views and just to use a single child view use the `Cardview`.

To simply put the overhead of the rounded edges and shadows: 
If you consider the Framelayout as a cake then the elevation is like the icing and rounded edges is like cherry topping. Its aesthetic with the icing and the topping but you have to shed additional bucks for the icing and cherry.

Comment: So, what you mean to say is `CardView` is only beneficical when used for Api>21. For Api<21 it works the same as `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @MohammedAli No, for API<21, it displays the shadows and corners with a custom implementation. So the benefit is in fact that the design is consistent across all API versions.

Comment: @Psypher please answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36393540/no-shadow-elevation-underneath-second-card-if-there-are-two-card-in-the-layout

Comment: FWIW, I've profiled the latest androidx `CardView`, and compared to using a  `FrameLayout`. The performance profile looks identical. There has to be some hit in there to render the shadow but I can't find it.