# Android - Why to use cardview instead of a 9 patch

Tags: android

I recently read about CardView for Android.

But, I find myself comfortable using 9 patches as background to get the same effect. It allows me to swap the 9 patch with other images for theming etc.

Can anybody tell me why I should use CardView instead of a proper 9 patch to achieve the same look?

Comment: why is it down voted? !

Comment: You could do some research; I just searched 'CardView advantage' and found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28794725/advantage-and-disadvantage-of-cardview), it could help you :)

Comment: @abbath Thanks for responding. But I think the link you gave doesnt answer my question, as to why I shall use cardview instead of a matching 9 patch.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use drawable (XML) as it is simplest. Developers might not love to spend their time in creating 9patch. 
Cardview gives you good look by providing you facility to configure radius, elevation etc attributes.

Comment: Yeah, but you can do the same with a nice shape drawable :)

Comment: Why to increase images in drawables? Particularly for larger projects.. As it might give you performance hit.. Think of listview having 1000 views whose background is set as 9patch.. Now UI have to render images 1000times!!.. This could make your application heavier

Comment: @AskQ If I am right, 9 patches wont add that much load on the memory as they are actually not stretched out as a big bitmap by android. at least with HWUI enabled. I believe its drawn with a 9patch mesh with proper texture coordinates to do the stretching part. So I think 9 patches are still a good way to go provided they can allow theming which Cardview probably cannot.